# .Net Reporting Engine with great Excel export features

Tags: .net, visual-studio, excel, reporting, export-to-excel

Our users love Microsoft Excel, like many of them.
Some of our reports are pretty complex. We are using SSRS right now.

One of the key problems with SSRS excel exports is that the users have to do a significant amount of little presentation adjustements after the file is exported.

Some of the reports are wide and do not fit the normal page in Excel, so they need to go to the Page Setup options in Excel and set the "Fit to Page" option.
Also margins are too wide by default. SSRS does not have any way to adjust this in the exported Excel file automatically.

There is also no way to my knowledge to freeze pane anywhere else than just after the header block, in the exported file automatically. Users need it to be set after the table's header columns, rather than the report header itself.

SSRS also does not support AutoFilter in Excel, users need to add these manually.

As you can see, it is a significant amount of rework that needs to be done by the users after the file has been exported.
I am looking for a decent and relatively well supported reporting engine that comes with a much better than average Excel-exporting features, in the page layout department in particular.

SSRS, Crystal Reports, Telerik, and others I have tried all lacked this kind of features.

I am now considering rewriting the reports in pure code using an Excel component like SpreadsheetGear... but the idea of dealing with all the formatting, colouring, totals, etc, in code makes me a bit reluctant as a lot of code will be devoted to just formatting and it would be difficult to support and error-prone.

Does anyone know of a great graphical reporting engine with great Excel exporting output, or has a better idea than generating the reports from scratch using code?

Thanks a lot in advance.

I am developping in .Net for the ASP.Net and WinForms platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [i-net Clear Reports.NET](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/clear-reports/editions/dot-net). It is a great reporting tool and it has also Excel as output format. Excel is not the main output format. But if Excel is your target output then it is possible to design the report templates that you receive the wanted output.

There is a also a good and fast support if you have problems with your features.

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly what I was looking for but probably the closest. The fact that it comes from the Java world is making me a bit anxious about .Net compatibility issues or less than ideal interface with it though (according to the website, seems to support only ODBC rather than .Net Data providers, etc)

Comment: Add support for other .NET Data provider should not be a problem. Contact the support with your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps have a look at something like WCF Data Services, which Excel (2010 only I believe) can consume directly.

You would manually create your excel templates to consume this once off (directly in Excel) but have them point to the live data so they are always up-to-date.